# Getting data from nested JSON objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

I am making a web application that can search and display movie content and I am trying to get access to outer objects such as **"title"** with nested objects like **"principals"** - fetched from the same endpoint.

**JSON response from fetch:**

```
{
  "title": "The Match Factory Girl",
  "year": 1990,
  "runtime": 69,
  "genres": [
    "Comedy",
    "Crime",
    "Drama"
  ],
  "country": "Finland, Sweden",
  "principals": [
    {
      "id": "nm0653669",
      "category": "actress",
      "name": "Kati Outinen",
      "characters": [
        "Iris Rukka"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "nm0758825",
      "category": "actress",
      "name": "Elina Salo",
      "characters": [
        "Mother"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ratings": [
    {
      "source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "value": 7.5
    },
    {
      "source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "source": "Metacritic",
      "value": null
    }
  ],
  "boxoffice": 0,
  "poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMmM1ZTZhNDUtYzBkNi00YzQ0LWEyZjItM2M5OTI2ZTU0MDlkXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMjI0MjMwMzQ@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "plot": "A woman's terribly dull life is upended by a one-night stand pregnancy, causing her to seek retribution."
}
```

My goal is to get the objects in "principles" to render on an AG grid, meanwhile having objects that aren't nested such as "title", "year", "runtime' etc. to display on  tags.

I have managed to get "principals" to show using useEffect() on an AG grid but I am lost in trying to also get "title" to display.

```
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
const columns = [
    {headerName: "Role", field: "role", sortable: true},
    {headerName: "Name", field: "name"},
    {headerName: "Characters", field: "characters"},
  ];


useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${API_URL}/movies/data/${imdbID}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(people => people.principals)
    .then(principals => 
      principals.map(person => {
        return {
          role: person.category,
          name: person.name,
          characters: person.characters,
          id: person.id
        }
    }))
    .then(allPeople => setRowData(allPeople))
    .then(test => console.log("ss"))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }, []);


return (
    <div>
        <h1> The title of the movie is... </h1>
        <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={{height: "300px", width: "1100px"}}>
          <AgGridReact columnDefs={columns}  rowData={rowData} pagination={true} paginationPageSize={7}/>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: You don't need to do all the refactoring within the fetch, and certainly not in successive `then` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Store the entire movie object in the state. Get the `year`, `title` and create the `rows` in the body of the component.

You can wrap the `rows` mapping with `useMemo` to avoid mapping it on each render, when `movie` doesn't change:

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState(null);

const { title, year, principals } = movie;

useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`${API_URL}/movies/data/${imdbID}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(setMovie) // store movie in the state
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}, []);

const rows = useMemo(() => principals.map(person => ({
  role: person.category,
  name: person.name,
  characters: person.characters,
  id: person.id
})), [movie])

return (
  <div>
    <h1> The title of the movie is {title} / {year}</h1>
    <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={{height: "300px", width: "1100px"}}>
      <AgGridReact columnDefs={columns}  rowData={rowData} pagination={true} paginationPageSize={7}/>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.. You're only returning principles from your api response. You need to return the whole object with the formatted principles, as follows

```
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);
const [data, setData] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(`${API_URL}/movies/data/${imdbID}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((people) => people)
    .then((people) => {
      return {
        ...people,
        principles: people.principals.map((person) => ({
          role: person.category,
          name: person.name,
          characters: person.characters,
          id: person.id,
        })),
      };
    })
    .then((allPeople) => {
      setData(allPeople);
      setRowData(allPeople.principals);
    })
    .then((test) => console.log('ss'))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    <h1> The title of the movie is: {data.title} </h1>
    <div
      className="ag-theme-balham"
      style={{ height: '300px', width: '1100px' }}
    >
      <AgGridReact
        columnDefs={columns}
        rowData={rowData}
        pagination={true}
        paginationPageSize={7}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
);
```